# Slow startup when extracting thumbnails from UDP live stream using FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running the following command using FFMpeg to extract an image every 1 second from a UDP stream:

`ffmpeg -i "udp://224.1.2.123:9001" -s 256x144 -vf fps=1 -update 1 test.jpg -y`

This works well, but it takes about 5 seconds to actually start producing images. Is there any way to lower the startup time?

The UDP stream uses mpegts format and is encoded with H264/AAC.

Thanks!

Comment: Start up delay will depend on keyframe interval in source stream.

Comment: My keyframe interval is 2 seconds, so it shouldn't be a 5 second delay.

Comment: Dropped packets?